# Can Delphi FireDAC work properly with SEE on android platform?

Tags: android, delphi, android-sqlite, delphi-xe7, firedac

I'm a newbie for android development.

I'm developing an mobile application run on Android devices with Delphi XE7. And now I'm searching the way to encrypt the sqlite database files accessed through FireDac on Android devices.

I've found The [SQLite Encryption Extension (SEE)](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html).

But I'm not sure if FireDac can work properly with SEE to manipulate sqlite databases on Android device. If it can, how to deploy SEE to an android device?

Please suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

FireDAC will not support SEE.  However, you could use the build-in encryption with FireDAC for SQLite.  That would save you from having to use multiple components for the same task.

Here is a link to the documentation on SQLite with FireDAC.  The encryption process is included.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC